# Ajax Based Multiple Auto Complete/ Auto Suggest Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I am trying to find some plugin like the one, used in this website search box auto suggest.
http://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/buy.html

The second auto suggest list is based on the first keyword selected. I already know that mootools are used for it. If somebody knows about any plugin like this, please any advise.
Your suggestions will be a great help

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus follow the link  http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/   you will get what you want

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this for mootools, then try this: http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootagify

demo that works with backspace bound:
http://fragged.org/mooTagify/Demo/

autocompleter for tags is built in. source code and also unit tests (via busterjs + syn) on my github page - https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mooTagify/